# Gulp, less and sourcemaps makes me crazy (not working)

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-less

Input:

**gulp.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/less/style.less')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))

});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3",
    "gulp-less": "~1.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4"
  }
}
```

src/less/style.less have a lot of imports only, any styles.

gulp less generated to map file and /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */ in the end of the file exists, but I don't see and links to actual less files in Crome Dev Tools and the content of map file is not looks like on file content generated by Grunt:

```
{"version":3,"names":[],"mappings":"","sources":["style.less"],"sourcesContent":["// MaxA styles\r\n@import (reference) 'base/_mixins';\r\n@import (reference) 'base/_variables';\r\n@import \"layout/_base.less\";\r\n\r\n// Magento\r\n@import \"magento\";\r\n//font\r\n@import \"font\";\r\n// Reset\r\n@import \"normalize\";\r\n@import \"print\";\r\n// Core CSS\r\n@import \"scaffolding\";\r\n@import .............................
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: >`"gulp-less": "~1.1.10"` - hmm, looks like very ancient version (~2014), most likely Less just did not support any sourcemaps by then).

Comment: O, yes, my friend, you are absolutely right. I'm new on this project and trying to reorganize all this garbage. Gulp-less updated to 4.0.0, everything is working fine for now. Thanks. Fresh look is very important some times.

Comment: Use latest `gulp-less 3.x` version. `4.0.0` is not stable yet (because of some bugs in `less 3.0.x` it ships with).

Comment: Thanks, I'll test on weekend. Absolutely terrible debugging in style of "loos like something happened". No any debugging if the watcher  started. I tried several solution and found the other wonderful bug of watcher: remove right bracker - git the error, but working, no fault, add the right bracket again (undo), save ... got the same error again. Can be fixed with watcher only. That's some hell, not compiler.